# String.equals don't return true even when it is

Tags: java, compiler-optimization

I have this small piece of simple code but I don't know why I can't get it to work:

```
tagName="Hello";
String value="Hello";
if (tagName!=null && tagName.equals(value))
{
    int io=0;
}
```

`tagName` is not `null` and clearly equals to `value` but the code never hits the line `int io=0`.

Comment: Are you sure you are running this code? What happens if you print the value of `tagName.equals(value)` before the if statement?

Comment: There's no output in the `if` block. Try adding a `println` statement or debug into it

Comment: Yes the code is running, I have breakpoint set at the `io=0` statement and I am debugging step by step it just skips the if statement as if it has returned false.

Comment: you are confused, the assignment certainly occurs. Now the assignment is pointless because once you leave the block, that variable goes away, so there is no point in doing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java may optimize out your assignment statement because it has no effect. You can put a System.out.println into that block, or you can move 'int io' to outside the if and just have an assignment inside the block.

Comment: Thank you it was the optimization, I had to place a lot of code in there but for now I was just checking with this dummy statement that if code runs fine till here and was getting really confused why it doesn't. Now when I made the block little meaningful the breakpoints hits fine. Must say this java optimization is surprising and confusing too.

Comment: You are right shekhar suman, you posted a very detailed reply and helped alot but i had already resolved the issue through what `bmargulies` suggested so accepted this one voted-up yours. If i could accept two answer i would have surely done that, I even up vote all your comments as a gratitude.

Comment: @shekharsuman you started by insulting the OP ('poor design'), that may have led to some unfavorable thought. But the net vote was 0 when you deleted it, so I'm not sure what all the fuss is about.

Comment: @bmargulies- I got my error, actually what I received was my mistake only. That has nothing to do with OP's question,but,rather my mis-assumption. It'd had been the answer if the OP had any runtime exception which was not the case. His answer is extremely correct and justified...